# Flutter CodeMagic failed build

Tags: flutter, cocoapods, codemagic

Hi guys i'd tried to use pod install in windows but seems not import dependences from flutter i have that error.. from codemagic

i solve this part... i'ts an pod install i follow guide to install pod in windows...now i have another issue.

```
enter code here

== Building for iOS ==

== /usr/local/bin/flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign ==

Warning: Building for device with codesigning disabled. You will have to manually codesign before deploying to device.
Building com.corte.takeaway for device (ios)...

Running pod install...
1.7s
Running Xcode build...

Xcode build done. 29.0s

Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'firebase_auth' not found
@import firebase_auth;
~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

Encountered error while building for device.

Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

Comment: Are you trying to build an iOS App in Windows?

Comment: yes i use ruby pod

Comment: Has it ever worked for you? Apple has never allowed for iOS software to be built on any other operating system that is not macOS.

Comment: nope no work..problem ...

Comment: You need to be using macOS to be able to produce iOS applications. With the exception of building a hackintosh, you will need a Mac computer.

Comment: @joão-soares I think Daniele uses Codemagic to build iOS on macOS. It's not a hackintosh. Codemagic provides remote access to macOS to make any changes to Xcode / pods that requires macOS computer

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Codemagic. But he seems to be trying to make the build in his machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its seems like you forget to add googleservice.plist file in your project. Error occors